# Setting absolute position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery plugin for the slider. It displays 3 items at a time, and adds a class `slick-active` to the active items.

I want to display only the middle item as full width but want to display only 50% of the first and last items, as shown in the following image:
[image]

For that purpose, I am trying to set the absolute position of 50%, but it does not seem to work. I am unable to figure out how to set the position to get the above results.

This is what I'm trying:

```
.slick-active:first-child{
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
}

.slick-active:last-child{
    position: absolute;
    right: -50%;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/yu76xt4f/

Comment: Can't you use "width" attribute instead of left and right. assign widths 25%,50% and 25% respectively.

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna I want to display only 50% of the actual image size so that the 50% is cut off

Answer (score 2):

I added the following CSS, which I don't recommend. as it is using `!important` in it. I am using `!important` to override the inline styling providing by the plugin.

**CSS**

```
.slick-slide.slick-active{
    width: 100px !important;
}

.slick-slide.slick-active + .slick-slide.slick-active{
    width: 400px !important;
}

.slick-slide.slick-active + .slick-slide.slick-active + .slick-slide.slick-active{
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu76xt4f/5/)**

Comment: I think user1355300 want to show only 50% of the original image. But if you provide width as 100px, it will reduce the original width.

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna then you can use `25%`, `50%` and `25%`.. I will update when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
Use position: relative instead of absolute. and provide fixed value instead of percentage.

```
.slick-active:first-child{
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
}

.slick-active:last-child{
       position: relative;
       left: -50px;
}

.slick-active {
     position: relative;
     left: -50px;
}
```